# What's up with the downvote pattern on this question?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, down-votes, specific-answer

[How to point to risks in a culture that awards optimism and punishes CYA](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/132313/9549)

Every answer here has 2 downvotes. I'm prepared to accept my answer was merits the DVs it got, but two downvotes on *all* answers?

I find this pattern unlikely to occur naturally, but I'm prepared to accept it happens. Does this look normal?

Comment: well, there is one answer that is 0/0 but it was posted at the time you wrote this...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know for a fact that there are some people here who believe that if you answer a bad question, you deserve a down-vote and follow this practice religiously.  I know this as they have stated it explicitly in chat.  (no names please)

So, no it's not unusual.

Comment: That explains it actually, that's one way to practice your free speech.

Answer (score 2):

> Does this look normal?

I don't see anything extremely unusual here.

If every question has 2 DVs it just means that two separate users didn't find any of the answers useful... that is something *very* likely to happen eventually in a site with thousands of users.

However, I would suggest to keep an eye on that post, in case any suspicious behavior happens again, or if the down-votes start to turn vindictive... but I wouldn't worry much about that post (which even seems that will be closed soon).

Comment: You're right, it just struck me as odd scrolling down and seeing -2s everywhere. Guess I'm tilting at windmills here...

Answer (score 1):

Maybe two of the close voters  have a policy to downvote answers on questions that they think should be obviously closed.